# qunit/browser works, but qunit/grunt fails with require.js

Tags: javascript, testing, requirejs, gruntjs, qunit

I've got a small [github project](https://github.com/tkoomzaaskz/tree) with two branches: master (stable) and qunit-require (unstable). I've got some tests written in qunit that I want to have runnable both in the browser and from grunt level. On `master` branch everything works fine, travis-CI passes. And on `qunit-require` branch I'm trying to add require.js for the tests, but I didn't succeed yet.

I can run tests from the browser by displaying `test/index.html`. But when I run `grunt` in the console, I get no assertions error and I've got no idea why:

```
tducin@tducin-workshop:~/Development/tree (qunit-require)$ grunt
Running "qunit:all" (qunit) task
Testing test/index.html Warning: 0/0 assertions ran (15ms) Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

I've got `src/` and `test/` directories as long as `bower_components/` where bower deps are stored. This is my `test/index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jsTreeStructure Test Runner</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/qunit/qunit/qunit.css" />
        <script src="../bower_components/qunit/qunit/qunit.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="qunit"></div>
        <div id="qunit-fixture"></div>
        <script src="../bower_components/requirejs/require.js" data-main="init.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my `test/init.js`:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '../',
    shim: {
        'underscore': {
            exports: '_'
        },
        'tree' : {
            exports: 'Tree'
        },
        'qunit' : {
            exports: 'QUnit'
        }
    },
    paths: {
        'underscore': 'bower_components/underscore/underscore',
        'qunit': 'bower_components/qunit/qunit/qunit',
        'tree': 'src/tree'
    }
});

require([
    'test/suites/basic', 'test/qunit-extend'
], function(BasicTests) {
    QUnit.config.autoload = false;
    QUnit.config.autostart = false;
    BasicTests.run();
    QUnit.load();
    QUnit.start();
});
```

and this is part of my `Gruntfile.js`:

```
/*global module:false*/
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    qunit: {
      all: ['test/index.html'],
      options: {
        timeout: 3000,
        coverage: {
          src: ['src/tree.js']
        }
      }
    },
  // [...]
  });

  // These plugins provide necessary tasks.
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-qunit');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

  // Default task.
  grunt.registerTask('test', ['qunit', 'jshint']);
  grunt.registerTask('build', ['uglify']);
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['test', 'build']);
};
```

Anyway, you can find entire content at github: https://github.com/tkoomzaaskz/tree/tree/qunit-require

My question is: what can I do to make grunt execute the assertions (i.e. what mistake did I make here)?

Comment: I just ran your tests and 63 assertions execute and pass. Did you already nail the problem?

Comment: Try putting the autoload and autostart to be false inside the actual config for the grunt task.

Comment: maybe you should try testem or karma